# Don't show row based on condition but sum values in parent group

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Say I'm working with the following resultset:

```
+---------+-------------+------------+
|  Group  | Groupmember | Production |
+---------+-------------+------------+
| Group A | Member 1    |          5 |
| Group A | Member 2    |          3 |
| Group B | Member 3    |          2 |
| Group B | Member 4    |          5 |
| Group C | Member 5    |          1 |
+---------+-------------+------------+
```

Grouping on column **Group** will result in a report in the following syntax:

```
+---------+-------------+------------+
|  Group  | Groupmember | Production |
+---------+-------------+------------+
| Group A |             |          8 |
|         | Member 1    |          5 |
|         | Member 2    |          3 |
| Group B |             |          7 |
|         | Member 3    |          2 |
|         | Member 4    |          5 |
| Group C |             |          1 |
|         | Member 5    |          1 |
+---------+-------------+------------+
```

Now I'm trying to only show detailrows in case **Production >= 5**, though I want to count every record for the group. Expected:

```
+---------+-------------+------------+
|  Group  | Groupmember | Production |
+---------+-------------+------------+
| Group A |             |          8 |
|         | Member 1    |          5 |
| Group B |             |          7 |
|         | Member 4    |          5 |
| Group C |             |          1 |
+---------+-------------+------------+
```

Using a filter on the detailrow will however result in **Production** not being summed in the group.

How can I not show records based on a condition but sum them in the parentgroup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that a filter will not work, but you can set the visibility of the detail rows to get your requirement.

I have created a simple table based on your data, which gives the full results as above:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now, set the visibility of the detail row:

[image]

Right click, then set the **Hidden** expression to:

```
=IIf(Fields!Production.Value >= 5, False, True)
```

Now you get the required results:

[image]

Comment: +1 Offcourse, you're right. Thanks for the outstanding answer.